# angular-material button change hover background

Tags: css, angular-material

I have an angular-material link button element:

```
<a mat-button>Link</a>
```

I wanted to change its hover background to a bold white color, so in my global styles.css file I defined:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)!important;
}
```

The link itself does not have any additional styles. I can see that the background color on hover has indeed changed to white, but to a very pale white, despite the fact that the opacity is set to 0.8. Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use `opacity` instead of the alpha channel of `rgba`. [See here for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251539/1684458).

Comment: @p4r1 Tried it, still no luck

Answer (score 3):

In your global styles.css you have that chance to overwrite directly, what mat-button does - normal and on hover:
example :

```
$white: white;

.mat-button {
  color: $white;
  background: $white;
}

.mat-button:hover {
  color: $white;
  background: $white;
}
```